# Extract data from string using pattern

Tags: c#, html, regex, string, vb.net

Hi I have very long string:

```
'bla bla bla... <img src="/uploads/photo.png" width="143" height="136" /> bla bla bla...'
```

and I want to extract from this long string: Image tag - width, height and of course path... maybe something like this:

```
<img src="*" width="*" height="*" />
```

But I don't know how to get "*" data. Can you please suggest me code to extract image path (`*`). Might be in C#, VB or Java... anything. Thanks!

Comment: You tagged yourself the solution use a **Regex**or **Trim** and a **Regex**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use regex to parse html. Use html parser insted. E.g. you can use  [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
var html = "bla... <img src=\"/uploads/photo.png\" width=\"143\" height=\"136\" /> bla...";
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var img = doc.DocumentNode.Element("img");
var src = img.Attributes["src"].Value;       // "/uploads/photo.png"
var width = img.Attributes["width"].Value;   // "143"
var height = img.Attributes["height"].Value; // "136"
```

Or [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp)

```
var parser = new HtmlParser();
var doc = parser.Parse(html);
var img = doc.QuerySelectorAll("img").FirstOrDefault();
var src = img.Attributes["src"].Value;       // "/uploads/photo.png"
var width = img.Attributes["width"].Value;   // "143"
var height = img.Attributes["height"].Value; // "136"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple JavaScript solution using Regex:

```
> s = 'bla bla bla... <img src="/uploads/photo.png" width="143" height="136" /> bla bla bla...'
> s.match(/<.*>/)[0]
'<img src="/uploads/photo.png" width="143" height="136" />'
```

Comment: I will use your Regex to extract html tag from long string and Sergey Berezovskiy's HtmlAgilityPack to parse it.